# Move files when they contain a specific word?

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to write a powershell script that looks through all files in a given directory and moves them to a different directory if a specific word has been found.

This is what i currently have:

```
$source = "Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Aufträge\RuheEKG_24HBP_Skript\Ursprung_test"
$hans = Get-ChildItem Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Aufträge\RuheEKG_24HBP_Skript\Ursprung_test -filter *.txt -recurse 
foreach($hans in $source) {
    select-string -list -pattern "24BHD" -path $source
}
```

Now what do i need to add to make the script move the files containing the string `24BHD`?

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to use `$hans` in `Select-String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, but the `foreach` syntax isn't doing what you think.

You need to use `foreach ($item in $hans)`, where `$hans` is the collection of files, and `$item` represents each 'file' in the array during the 'loop'.

(the `$item` variable name can be anything you want, that's just an example I've used)

The `FullName` property contains the full path to the file, which is needed for for `Select-String -Path`.

Then use `Move-Item` if `Select-String` returns a match:

```
$source = 'Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Aufträge\RuheEKG_24HBP_Skript\Ursprung_test'
$destination = 'C:\Destination'
$pattern = '24BHD'

$hans = Get-ChildItem $source -filter *.txt -recurse 

foreach($item in $hans) {
    if (Select-String -list -pattern $pattern -path $item.fullname) {
        Move-Item -Path $item.fullname -Destination $destination
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me what i did wrong and how to fix it!
Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

```
$source = 'Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Aufträge\RuheEKG_24HBP_Skript\Ursprung_test'   
$dest = 'c:\dest'
Get-ChildItem $source -filter *.txt -recurse | Select-String -List -Pattern "24BHD" | ForEach-Object {
    Move-Item $PSItem.Path -Destination $dest
}
```

---

**Edit:**
This example is better, only using piping. The output of Get-ChildItem is piped to Select-String that filters out the files that contain "24BHD" in the content. The matching files are piped to Move-Item. In the above example I used Foreach-Object because I thought Move-Item can't handle the output of Select-String. That was unnecessary because PowerShell's parameter binding resolves that perfectly.

There's still a caveat: if duplicate filenames exist in de folder structure $source, Move-Item will run into a name conflict in the $dest folder

```
$source = 'Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Aufträge\RuheEKG_24HBP_Skript\Ursprung_test'   
$dest = 'c:\dest'

Get-ChildItem $source -filter *.txt -recurse | 
  Select-String -List -Pattern "24BHD" |
  Move-Item -Destination $dest
```

More on parameter binding can be found here: https://4sysops.com/archives/parameter-binding-in-the-powershell-pipeline/

Comment: @MathieuVIALES Added a better version and wrote some explanation. Hope that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `-match` comparison like so:

```
$source = "Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Aufträge\RuheEKG_24HBP_Skript\Ursprung_test"
$dest = "C:\destination\directory"
$find = "24BHD"

foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem "$source\*.txt" -Recurse)) {
    if ($file.Name -match $find) {
        Move-Item $file $dest
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the file Name that needs to be matched, but the content of the file, hence the `Select-String`