# Using PowerShell only copy folders (and contents within) that don't contain a string

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a long list of folders. Most of the folders follow the "name_#name" format. I have some that don't follow that structure. I want to move all the folders (and the sub-folders/files within) that DON'T have "_" in the folder name.

For example:
test_#12352
moose_#4532
horse_#84462
cow24
fish3

Moved:
cow24
fish3

I think [Move files when they contain a specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54234917/move-files-when-they-contain-a-specific-word) could be modified to make it work...just not sure how. I'm used to just using GUI, this is my first time using PowerShell

When I tried using that code in that link it didn't work with my situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is just filter the list before you move any files

So you can use the following to pick up all the files you want

```
$Files = Get-childItem -Path $Path -File
```

You can then filter it down. My favourite way is to pipe the variable into `Where-Object` and play around with the individual properties and match types. Since you don't want to include the `_` we can use a `-notmatch "_"` to exclude those values

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File | Where-object{$_.Name -notmatch "_"}
```

And finally, you can move the files

```
$Files | move-item -path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination
```

Or as a one liner

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File | Where-object{$_.Name -notmatch "_"} | move-item -path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination
```

*Please note I haven't really tested this code. So test it out yourself before you run it

Comment: This is what I used: 

`Get-ChildItem -Path "K:\Archive\Users" $Path -File | Where-object{$_.Name -notmatch "_"} | move-item -path "K:\Archive\Users" $_.FullName -Destination "K:\Archive\UsersNoID" $Destination -WhatIf`

and I got an error. Not sure whats wrong? It said something about "null" but I dont know what that does with this

Comment: Just tried `Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path C:\Users | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "_"} | % {Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination <destination_folder>` and it worked. thank you!